# How to solve that PDO Drivers is no value, but SQLite3 already installed

Tags: php, nginx-config

php7.2-sqlite3 were installed already, but PDO doesn't enable.

phpinfo() shows that:

```
PDO drivers:            no value
SQLite3 module version: 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2
SQLite Library:         3.27.2"
```

How can I enable PDO?

nginx version: nginx/1.15.10
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I'm very new to PHP. Can anyone help to tell me where log is, and how I could get detail information to know what happened?

Comment: Pleae have a look into your php.ini file to enable PDO - for more see https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: @PowerStat, thanks for your advice.  I did the same things in another Ubuntu 18.04 server, which works well and I could see that the PDO driver is sqlite with phpinfo(). But their configuration files in fpm/conf.d and php.ini are exactly the same. Changing php.ini couldn't seem to solve this issue.

Comment: I have not much experience with Ubuntu, but sometimes there are shadow config files ... but maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing with those two servers, their config files are the same, but sqlite libraries are different. The server, which can work, don't have sqlite.out, it is compiled from official source code, and it takes priority over any other but can't work as PDO driver. 
The problem was fixed by removing sqlite.out.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep sqlite
ii  libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64                    5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1                          amd64        Qt 5 SQLite 3 database driver
ii  libsqlite3-0:amd64                         3.22.0-1                                     amd64        SQLite 3 shared library
ii  php7.2-sqlite3                             7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                      amd64        SQLite3 module for PHP
ii  sqlite.out                                 555-1                                        amd64        sqlite3x

$ sudo apt purge sqlite.out
$ sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```